# redis sets and examples

Tags: redis, set

Been using for a few weeks now, and I'm so impressed; the amount
I have achieved and the time saved just from using the smallest
set of commands is great.

Using Wikipedia as my data, I made a small spider to grab all the
pages on wikipedia and download them..

I use redis to simply keep a record of which pages have been downloaded,
to prevent duplicates.

As each page is downloaded I execute:

```
sadd wiki pagename
```

And check each page for existence with:

```
sismember wiki pagename
```

Wow, sorry for the over explanation..   My question is , what do the following
commands do and when would they be likely used or be useful.

```
sdiff
sinter
sunion
```

sdiff = subtract multiple sets..

Answer (score 0):

I think [sdiff](http://redis.io/commands/sdiff), [sinter](http://redis.io/commands/sinter) and [sunion](http://redis.io/commands/sunion) are reasonably explained with examples in redis [commands](http://redis.io/commands) documentation. These are classic [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28mathematics%29) math operations which are useful in various situations where you need to manipulate data among multiple sets which might consist of similar or same items.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a bookstore and you want to figure out what genres are related so you can make recommendations for books in related genres. Not quite the now classic "customers who bought this also bought X", but more like recommending fantasy books to people who are interested in science fiction, say.

One way to do this would be to assign a ID to every customer, and for each purchased book put that ID in a set that represents a genre. If you want to know which genres are related you can then use set operations to find interesting metrics. One of these is the Jacard index, the size of the intersection divided by the size of the union -- in other words the number of customers who have bought at least a book from each genre, divided by the number of customers who  have bough a book in any of the genres. A lower index means less similarity, a higher index means closer similarity. An index of zero means no one has bought a book from both genres, and an index of one means that everyone who bought a book in one genre also bought a book in another.

You could also use the set difference to calculate the number of customers who bought a book in one genre that did not buy a book in the other (and if the two genres are similar, perhaps suggest to these that they should try a book from the other genre).